# how to perform Patch request in robot framework with nested JSON format

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to send below json format through patch on session,but don't know how to create it in Robot Framework.
Normal patch I can use create dictionary to handle.
But have no idea about nested JSON.

```
{
    "Boot": {
        "Boot_Order": [
            "device_1",
            "device_2"
            ]
        }
}
```

Below is part of my test case:

```
${select}=    CREATE LIST    device_1    device_2
${combine_body} =    CREATE DICTIONARY    Boot={}    Boot_Order=${select}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current script outputs a dictionary with two keys and their own values like

```
{ "Boot": "{}", "Boot_Order": ["device_1", "device_2"] }
```

To achieve a nested dictionary, you'd need to create first the inner dictionary and then assign that inner dictionary under some key to the outer dictionary. Consider following:

```
${select}=    Create List    device_1    device_2
${inner_dict}=    Create Dictionary    Boot_Order=${select}
${outer_dict}=    Create Dictionary    Boot=${inner_dict}
```

This would have an output you are looking for

```
{ "Boot": {"Boot_Order": ["device_1", "device_2"]}}
```

If you have a lot of complexity in the JSON outputs and you can template the content, it might make sense to look also into the [JSON Library for Robot Framework](https://robotframework-thailand.github.io/robotframework-jsonlibrary/JSONLibrary.html).

Comment: that would be great helpful!
Thank you!